# Cookie modal não funciona?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Construi o seguinte código para que o mesmo preservasse um cookie da abertura e fechamento do modal, para que não fosse exibido em um periodo de 24h, mas o mesmo não funciona por algum motivo que desconheço, pela lógica o código o mesmo parece estar correto. segue os códigos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If para mostrar ou ocultar a mensagem
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#modal').show();
  }

   // Adiciona o evento "fechar"
  // Assim não exibe novamente
  $('#botao').click(function() {
    $('#modal').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
  });

});

// ---
// Lócica do cookie
// ---
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

```css
.success {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .error {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }

  
  .modalfox {
    font-family: "forzabook", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(/arquivos/modal-fox-brasil.png);
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.42;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-position: center center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 350px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 550px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    z-index: 100001;
    top: 2%;
    left: 40%;
    height: 600px
  }
  
  .reModalMask .newsletter {
    font-family: "forzabook", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 440px;
  }
  
  input.newsletter-client-email {
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "forzabook", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  input.newsletter-client-name {
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "forzabook", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .newsletter p {
    display: none!important;
  }
  
  .newsletter h3 {
    display: none!important;
  }
 
  
  .reModalMask {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
  
  #botao {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  #botao:hover {
    background-color: black;
    border: solid black 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    .reModalMask {
      display: none!important;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reModalMask" id="reModalMask">
  <div class="col-md-12 modalfox" id="modal">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" title="Não quero receber promoções da FOX!" id="botao">X</a>

    <vtex.cmc:newsletterOptIn />
  </div>
</div>
```

Alguém teria uma luz ? desde já agradeço!

Comment: Isso aqui ' document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; ' , não deveria ser nesse padrão document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

Comment: Não entendi esse padrão que citou, poderia ser mais especifico ? Obrigado pela resposta...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Ele estabelece um padrão ali hmmm beleza irei tentar obrigado!

Comment: Tenta remover o "!", do primeiro "if".